# Fit and find fitting parameters of data given an equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fitting, physics, code-request

If I have the following data:

```
data= {{-2., 0.147789}, {-1.52288, 0.237749}, {-1., 0.476084}, {-0.522879, 
  0.641128}, {-4.82164*10^-17, 1.04976}, {0.477121, 1.43399}, {1., 
  1.77276}, {1.47712, 2.23469}, {2., 2.46328}, {2.47712, 
  2.85828}, {3., 2.96392}, {3.47712, 2.91354}, {4., 3.02119}}
```

which plotted as:

`ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1 , Frame -> True,  Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 13],  FrameLabel -> {Style["Log t(s)", 16],  Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalDelta]H\), \ \(a\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Jg\), \(-1\)]\))", 16]}]`

gives:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How can I fit that data to the following equation using Mathematica:

[image]

Where `ΔHa (ta)` is what I am plotting in the y-axis, `t` is what I am plotting in the x axis (notice that time is in Log10 scale in the x-axis of the plot) and `τ0` and `β` are the best fitting parameters of the equation. `ΔHa(∞)` is simply the average of the last three data calculated as `DHinfinity = Mean[{3.02119, 2.91354, 2.96392}]`

2. How can i get the fitting parameters `τ0` and `β`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{-2., 0.147789}, {-1.52288, 0.237749}, {-1., 
    0.476084}, {-0.522879, 0.641128}, {-4.82164*10^-17, 
    1.04976}, {0.477121, 1.43399}, {1., 1.77276}, {1.47712, 
    2.23469}, {2., 2.46328}, {2.47712, 2.85828}, {3., 
    2.96392}, {3.47712, 2.91354}, {4., 3.02119}};

{logtmin, logtmax} = MinMax[data[[All, 1]]]

(* {-2., 4.} *)

DHinfinity = Mean[data[[All, 2]][[-3 ;;]]]

(* 2.96622 *)
```

**EDIT:** Corrected model to use `Log10[t]` vice `Log[t]`.  This does not change the fit, merely the parameter values. Also added constraint that `0 <  b < 1` (unnecessary in this particular case)

```
(nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
    data, {DHinfinity (1 - Exp[-(10^logt/tau)^b]), 0 < b < 1}, {tau, b}, 
    logt]) // Normal

(* 2.96622 (1 - E^(-0.40494 (10^logt)^0.356033)) *)

nlm["BestFitParameters"]

(* {tau -> 12.6687, b -> 0.356033} *)

Plot[nlm[logt], {logt, logtmin, logtmax},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 13],
 FrameLabel -> {Style[StringForm["`` t (s)", Subscript[Log, 10]], 16], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ΔH\), \ \
\(a\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Jg\), \(-1\)]\))", 16]},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Bob Hanlon, thank you very much. The code is fantastic and works great! I really appreciate it !

Comment: Yes, added (unnecessary) constraint and corrected to use `Log10` vice `Log`