# Problem with fitting a given data with an equation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, physics, code-request

I want to fit a given data using the approach developed by @Bob Hanlon here: [Fit and find fitting parameters of data given an equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236871/fit-and-find-fitting-parameters-of-data-given-an-equation)

I have tried this approach for several different data sets but I have one in particular where the equation does not seem to fit the data very well but it is not very clear to me why or if I can "tweak the equation" or the parameters to make it fit well.

Here's the my data and the code I am using:

```
hey = {{-2.`, 0.3650687761296365`}, {-1.5228787452803376`, 
   0.35024185145494713`}, {-1.`, 
   0.35008362652827657`}, {-0.5228787452803376`, 
   0.35002569469868255`}, {-4.821637332766436`*^-17, 
   0.3690654823479624`}, {0.4771212547196624`, 
   0.4295109082336017`}, {1.`, 
   0.5336781026939912`}, {1.4771212547196624`, 
   0.7942359842488445`}, {2.`, 
   1.3736241822734323`}, {2.4771212547196626`, 
   2.0178692522958217`}, {3.`, 
   2.2855926539783797`}, {3.477121254719662`, 
   2.2855974030998034`}, {4.`, 2.2855975424841546`}}

(nlmp = NonlinearModelFit[
    hey, {2.2856 (1 - Exp[-(10^logt/tauc)^bc]), bc <= 1}, {tauc, bc}, 
    logt]) // Normal

nlmp["BestFitParameters"]

Show[
 
 ListPlot[hey, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 13}, AspectRatio -> 1 , 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Medium,
   AspectRatio -> 1, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 13], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Log (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(a\)]\) / s)",
      16], 
    Style["\[CapitalDelta]H (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Jg\), \(-1\)]\))",
      16]}, PlotLabel -> Style[Ta[[8 + 1]] "ºC", Black, 14]],
 
 Plot[nlmp[logt], {logt, -2.2, 4.2}, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 13], 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["Log (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(a\)]\) / s)",
      16], Style[
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[CapitalDelta]H\), \(a\)]\) (J/g)", 16]}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[datac]}]
 
 ]
```

Which gives the following fit:

[image]

I have also tried simply using

`(nlmp = NonlinearModelFit[hey, {2.2856 (1 - Exp[-(10^logt/tauc)^bc])**+ 0.35**, bc <= 1}, {tauc, bc},logt]) // Normal`

and it of course fixes the fit in the bottom part but now the problem is in the upper part.

**Question:**

What is wrong with this particular data set and How could I modified the equation to make a correct fit (the lower part of the data is not correctly fitted)?

For reference, the fitting equation that I am using in `nlmp` is:

[image]

Comment: Frankly, I don't see how that formula can possibly fit that data. The asymptotic behaviour simply doesn't match. You could just throw in a fudge y-axis offset parameter, but there needs to be a clear physical or experimental motivation for that.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit thanks for your comment. One of my problems is that I do not know how to modify it "slightly" to make the data fit. For example, I used `(nlmp = NonlinearModelFit[hey, {2.2856 (1 - Exp[-(10^logt/tauc)^bc])**+ 0.35**, bc <= 1}, {tauc, bc},logt]) // Normal` and it fixes the bottom part but now the upper part is wrong. There must be a very simple combination where it can fit it completely, no?. I guess in my case, there is no need for that to have a physical meaning

Comment: To keep the original definition for `delHinf` the asymptotic behavior would be `Ha == offset + (delHinf - offset) (1 - Exp[-(10^logt/tauc)^bc])`

Comment: @BobHanlon again so helpful! Thank you very much for this suggestion!. That's the best combination to not modified the original definition of `delHinf`. Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equation you show will never fit your data because it cannot reproduce the asymptotic behavior at negative `logt`. You need to add a constant vertical offset for it do so:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   hey, {deltaHinf (1 - E^-(10^logt/tau0)^beta) + const, beta <= 1},
   {{deltaHinf, 2.2}, {beta, 0.6}, {tau0, 200}, {const, 0.2}},
   logt
   ];

Show[
 Plot[nlm[logt], Evaluate@Flatten@{logt, MinMax[hey[[All, 1]]]}],
 ListPlot[hey, PlotStyle -> Black]
]

nlm["BestFitParameters"]

(* Out: {deltaHinf -> 1.9366, 
         beta -> 0.878246, 
         tau0 -> 138.601, 
         const -> 0.351186} *)
```

[image: fitted data]

**BUT!!** (and this is a big but), *can you justify that offset physically within your model?*

Comment: MarcoB thank you very much! You are always so helpful with your answers. One quick question: Is there any way to get what you got without changing the value of `deltaHinf`?. For example, only by changing the values of `beta`, `tau` and perhaps a `constant`?

Comment: @John No, there isn't. The point is: the value of $\Delta H_{inf}$ is the *difference* between the max and the min asymptotes (i.e. the value at high logt and the `const` in the model). The fact that the highest value is 2.28 in your data doesn't mean that this is the value of $\Delta H_{inf}$ unfortunately. If, on the other hand, $\Delta H_{inf}$  *has to be* equal to the value at highest `logt`, then we go back to the fact that this equation is not a good model for this dataset...

Comment: Upvoted for the big but at the end!

Comment: Of course it's justified! See [here](https://xkcd.com/2048/)